# ora:12505:TNS: listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor (DBD ERROR: OCIServerAttach)

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Agent Connection to Instance
 Status
 Failed
 Details
 ORA-12505:

> TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor (DBD ERROR: OCIServerAttach)

Listener file

**listener.ora Network Configuration File:**

E:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\listener.ora

```
Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

LISTENER =

 (DESCRIPTION_LIST =

    (DESCRIPTION =

      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))

      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 169.254.52.209)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

ADR_BASE_LISTENER = E:\app\Administrator
```

**tnsnames.ora** file

tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File:

E:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\tnsnames.ora

```
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

EDSS =

  (DESCRIPTION =

    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 169.254.52.209)(PORT = 1521))

    (CONNECT_DATA =

      (SERVER = DEDICATED)

      (SERVICE_NAME = edss)
    )
  )
```

The listener status

```
C:\Users\Administrator>lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 17-MAR-2014 09:06:11

Copyright (c) 1991, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))

STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                    LISTENER

Version                  TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production

Start Date               16-MAR-2014 16:50:30

Uptime                   0 days 16 hr. 15 min. 45 sec

Trace Level              off

Security                 ON: Local OS Authentication

SNMP                     OFF

Listener Parameter File   E:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\listener.ora

Listener Log File         e:\app\administrator\diag\tnslsnr\server\listener\alert\log.xml

Listening Endpoints Summary...

(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1521ipc)))

(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=169.254.52.209)(PORT=1521)))

The listener supports no services

The command completed successfully

"Agent connection to instance status is failed. I could not find out where is the issue"
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`lsnrctl status`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14213/lsnrctl.htm) command replied "The listener supports no services". There is a network listener running but it hasn't been told about any databases.

You need to add services to your [listener.ora file](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28316/listenercfg.htm#i486171).  Add a sid_list to your listener.ora like below, then restart the listener.

```
 LISTENER =
 (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
  (DESCRIPTION =
   (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
   (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 169.254.52.209)(PORT = 1521))
  )
 )

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
(SID_LIST =
 (SID_DESC=
  (GLOBAL_DBNAME=edss.your.domain.here)
  (ORACLE_HOME=E:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1)
  (SID_NAME=edss)
 )
)

ADR_BASE_LISTENER = E:\app\Administrator
```

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple reasons for this issue:

Recently I faced a similar problem with my Oracle 11g on Windows 7 machine. I found that in `services.msc`,  `OracleOraDb11g_home1ClrAgent` was not started and its startup type was set to MANUAL.

I changed the startup type to AUTOMATIC and started `OracleOraDb11g_home1ClrAgent` manually, after that I was able to connect properly.

So the basic reason was that `OraClrAgnt` isn't running.

For other reasons you can check [this link](http://dba-oracle.com/t_ora_12514_tns_listener_does_not_currently_know_service_requested.htm).

Comment: These are my listener status and tnsnames

Comment: # listener.ora Network Configuration File: E:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 169.254.52.209)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

ADR_BASE_LISTENER = E:\app\Administrator   @san

Comment: # tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: E:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

EDSS =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 169.254.52.209)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = edss)
    )
  )          @san

Comment: Try to run `lsnrctl start edss` on Oracle Server and then log in. This will start listener for `edss` service.

Comment: while running this command the message is "Listener using listener name LISTENER has already been started...{is any line missing in the Listener.ora above}

Answer (score 0):

if you are facing this issue while setting up oracle sql server you need to follow the procedure mentioned below
first identify weather Database is detected or not in the welcome page as shown
step 1:
[Database Detected image][1]

step 2:
navigate to the directory path
E:\Study\SQL\WINDOWS.X64_193000_db_home\network\admin

step 3:
Open the file in notepad :

step 4 :
check service name  (in my case it was orcl)

[tnsnames.ora description][2]

step 5:
go to add connection :

step 6:
set- up a new connect as follows :
[Oracle Sql developer new connection set-up][3]

Name : specify any as per your requirement
user : sys (if you wanted to create using system administrator)
password : which have set up during set-up
hostname : localhost (for local run only)
Port : 1521
service name : orcl (enter the service name which you have seen in step 4)
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWpgX.jpg
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHm4f.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQ4T8.png

step 7: click on test and connect
it should connect with your oracle database.

Note: While testing I have been using Oracle version 23.1.0.097

cheers !