# TNS listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, database-connection

Hi,
I have installed `Oracle 11g` on my laptop for practicing Oracle.
I've connected to the HR account. It has been connected for 3 days, but after that I was getting this error when I tried to connect through SQL Developer:

```
TNS-12505: TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor
```

Comment: please share what error message showing

Comment: Without the error in question we cannot help you at all, ever.  Please share the verbatim text of the error.  Thanks!

Comment: error message:TNS-12505: TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor

Comment: What connection method are you using (e.g. JDBC)? Can you connect using SQL\*Plus?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18192521/ora-12505-tnslistener-does-not-currently-know-of-sid-given-in-connect-descript)

Comment: I just tried to correct the question title to the actual error message (it's not *'Listener currently doesn't know the sid of given connect descriptor'*, it's *'Listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor'*) but there are already many questions for the same error message and SO requires titles to be unique. Maybe you could looks at some of the others in case they help.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that

- Your DB is ***started up*** ;

  ```
  $ sqlplus / as sysdba
  SQL> startup
  ```
- ***ORACLE_SID*** *parameter* is set to a path value;

  on ***Windows***, look-up by :

  ```
  C:\Users\pc> echo %ORACLE_SID%
  mydb
  ```

  on ***Unix***, look-up by :

  ```
  $ echo $ORACLE_SID
  mydb
  ```
- and ***Listener*** is running :

  ```
  $ lsnrctl status
  LSNRCTL for Linux : Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production on 03-JUN-2018 09:31:07

  Copyright (c) 1991, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

  Connecting to (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=)(PORT=1521))
  STATUS of the LISTENER
  ------------------------
  Alias                     LISTENER
  Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
  Start Date                30-MAR-2018 22:29:45
  Uptime                    53 days 11 hr. 1 min. 10 sec
  Trace Level               off
  Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
  SNMP                      OFF
  Listener Parameter File   /u01/app/12.1.0.2/grid/network/admin/listener.ora
  Listener Log File         /u01/app/grid/diag/tnslsnr/mydb/listener/alert/log.xml
  Listening Endpoints Summary...
   (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=LISTENER)))
   (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=172.16.15.81)(PORT=1521)))
   (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=mycompany.com)(PORT=5505))(Presentation=HTTP)(Session=RAW))
   (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcps)(HOST=mycompany.com)(PORT=5506)) 
   (Security=(my_wallet_directory=/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/dbhome_1/admin/mydb/xdb_wallet))(Presentation=HTTP)(Session=RAW))
    Services Summary...
   Instance "mydb", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
   The command completed successfully
  ```

Comment: I'm sorry. I have similar problem and want to know what could I do to solve the issue, if my output is:

`[oracle@oracl oracle]$ lsnrctl status
...
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=oracl)(PORT=1521)))
...
Listener Parameter File    path_to/listener.ora
Listener Log File         path_to/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=oracl)(PORT=1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
The listener supports no services
The command completed successfully`

Comment: @Gryu perhaps you need to register the listener by `SQL> alter system register;`

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not help. But this answer helped: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22437910/ora12505tns-listener-does-not-currently-know-of-sid-given-in-connect-descript
My listener.ora file was lack of:
`SID_LIST_LISTENER =
(SID_LIST =
 (SID_DESC=
  (GLOBAL_DBNAME=oracl)
  (ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1)
  (SID_NAME=orcl)
 )
)
ADR_BASE_LISTENER=/u01/app/oracle`

Comment: Also, interesting, that now `lsnrctl status` command shows the status as unknown: `Services Summary...
Service "oracl" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...`. Is it bad?

Comment: @Gryu might be encountered such a message usually, not important, but restart may be preferred.

Answer (score 0):

You should try the following ways and one of them may work for you.

Way-1: In windows: use this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lOTwdaI_05A): restart services `OracleOraDB19Home1TNSListener` then `OracleServiceORCL`.

Way-2: connect with `system` user password to `sql plus` as shown as:

```
Enter user-name: system/ as sysdba
Enter password: your_password

SQL> shutdown
SQL> startup nomount
SQL> alter system set db_recovery_file_dest_size=4G scope=both;
SQL> alter database mount;
SQL> alter database open;
```

And now check your problem fixed? If no set below code then check again.

```
SQL> alter system set local_listener='(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)   (HOST=127.0.0.1) (PORT=1521)))';
```

This work for me.